# I'm having problems whilst creating a quiz using python loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, while-loop

The start of my code works fine but,the bottom part consisting on the score and answer doesn't. I'm doing a school project on this and need a solution quick. But I have to be using loops! The part where i'm trying to tell the user that the answer is correct isn't working. The part where i'm revealing the right answer isn't working as well. The score isn't working as well.

```
print ('WELCOME TO THE MULTIPLE CHOICE TEST\n')
name = input('WHAT IS YOUR NAME? ')
print ('\nHI THERE ' + name + '! LET''S PLAY A GAME!\n')
print ('I will ask you 10 questions and give you three choices for each question.\n\nYou select which choice is the correct answer. Eg. A, B,C or D\n')

score = 0
score = int(score) 

qn1 = ["What's color of sky?", "a)Red", "b)Blue", "c)White", "d)Black"]


def print_question(qn_num):
    print(qn_num[0])

    print(qn_num[1])
    print(qn_num[2])
    print(qn_num[3])
    print(qn_num[4])

print_question(qn1)

answer = input ()
answer =int(answer)
if answer == 2:
   print ("good work")
   score = score + 1

else:

    print ("better luck next time")

    score = score - 1
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Edit your question and explain what the expected behavior is and what the actual behavior is; include any error messages Python produces.

Comment: Don't add a comment, Joshua. Edit your question and *explain* what isn't working. Just saying *"it isn't working"* isn't helpful in describing your issue.

Comment: If you have to use loops, I'd expect a `for` or `while` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the answer in an infinite loop, and also show the score

```
print ('WELCOME TO THE MULTIPLE CHOICE TEST\n')
name = input('WHAT IS YOUR NAME? ')
print ('\nHI THERE ' + name + '! LET''S PLAY A GAME!\n')
print ('I will ask you 10 questions and give you three choices for each question.\n\nYou select which choice is the correct answer. Eg. A, B,C or D\n')

score = 0
score = int(score) 

qn1 = ["What's color of sky?", "a)Red", "b)Blue", "c)White", "d)Black"]


def print_question(qn_num):
  for st in qn_num:
    print(st)

print_question(qn1)

allowed_answers = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
wrong_answer = True
while(wrong_answer):
  answer = input ("select answer: ")

  if answer == 'b':
   print ("good work")
   score = score + 1
   wrong_answer = False
  elif answer not in allowed_answers:
    print ("Bad input, you have to chose between " + ",".join(allowed_answers) )
  else:
    print ("better luck next time")
    score = score - 1
  print("Your score is: " + str(score))
```

Comment: I want the user to input a letter though, is there any way around that ?

Comment: @joshuaebenezer sure, I made an update to the answer, don't forget mark the question as accepted if worked for you, top left of the answer, clicking the check box

Comment: After the line `answer = input ("select answer: ")` do `while len(answer)!=1: 
 answer = input("Please only enter one character! ")`

Comment: @DamianLattenero  In order to make my code really robust I need to tell the user only to enter a,b,c or d. What if they enter g or f for example how can I prevent this?

Comment: You can check if answer is in a,b ,c , d. If not print wrong choice and continue. Like after `answer = input(...` use `if answer not in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'): print ('Wrong choice') continue`

Comment: @joshuaebenezer did you uncheck the answer? what happend? something wrong with the code?

Comment: @DamianLattenero yeah the code displays select answer continuously even after the question has been answered. In order to make my code really robust I need to tell the user only to enter a,b,c or d. What if they enter g or f for example how can I prevent this?

Comment: @joshuaebenezer ok I made a last edit, but remember, you can ask one question at the time, now you have a base code, if you have new doubts, you have to make new answers, if not is confusing for future readers, and the answer will be edited a lot of times, and the original question is missing. I hope you understand :), is how this site works. I think it work just fine now

Comment: @idjaw thanks for the support here, I know is not the most interest answer about python, but it took some time :)